# Flutter: AnimatedList animation curve

Tags: flutter, animation, flutter-animation

How can I add a curve (e.g. Curves.easeIn) to the animation of my AnimatedList?

```dart
AnimatedList(
  key: _animList,
  initialItemCount: _myList.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index, animation) {
    return SlideTransition(
      position: animation.drive(Tween(begin: Offset(1, 0), end: Offset(0, 0))), <-- curve?
      child: Container(color: Colors.red, height: 100, width: 100)
    );
  }
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should invoke **chain** method on the **Tween**. The **chain** method takes a **CurveTween** and the **CurveTween** takes a **curve**

Try this

```
    AnimatedList(
        key: _animList,
        initialItemCount: _myList.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index, animation) {
          return SlideTransition(
              position: animation.drive(
                  Tween(begin: Offset(1, 0), end: Offset(0, 0))
                      .chain(CurveTween(curve: Curves.bounceIn))),
              child: Container(color: Colors.red, height: 100, width: 100));
        });
```

Comment: thanks a lot! Did the trick! :) Is there a way to set the duration of the animation?

Comment: Before return try  **animation.duration = Duration(seconds: 2);**

Comment: Didn't work. I get "The setter 'duration' isn't defined for the class 'Animation<double>'".

Comment: Ooooppsssssssss